# Can't resolve react path alias

Tags: reactjs, typescript, path, relative-import

Edit: I solved it, in the comments.

I'm trying to use alias for paths but I can't seem to get it to work I keep getting this error even though this path is correctly predicted by vs code.

This is a typescript-redux template I just created I'm trying to import the Counter.tsx in App.tsx

```
Compiled with problems:
ERROR in ./src/App.tsx 7:0-53
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '$/features/counter/Counter' in '\frontend\src'
```

I added these to tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "$/*": ["*"] //Tried both @ and $ incase @ doesn't work
       //Tried the above and the below one with switching @ and $ everytime to make sure it's not the symbol
      "@/*": ["./*"] // I tried both @ and $ also 
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

frontend/src/features/counter/Counter.tsx => counter

```
    export function Counter() {
      return (
        <div>
        ...
        </div>
      );
    }
```

I tried to import as

```
import { Counter } from "@/features/counter/Counter";
import { Counter } from "$/features/counter/Counter";

and without the {}
```

this is the folder structure

```
frontend
├── node_modules
├── public
├── src
│   ├──App.tsx (where I'm importing the Counter) 
│   ├──app
│   ├──features
│   ├──├──counter
│   ├──├──├──Counter.tsx
├── tsconfig.json
```

I can't seem to get it to work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by installing few packages not sure which worked but mainly craco which bypassed webpack settings I think anyways here goes the solution:

1. Install these packages

   ```
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.36.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.36.1",
    "craco-alias": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "^1.1.2",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
   ```
2. Create these files if you don't already have it

   ```
    craco.config.js
    tsconfig.paths.json
    tsconfig.json
   ```
3. Add these to files

tsconfig.json

```
    "compilerOptions":{//leave as is},
     "include": ["src"],
      "exclude": ["node_modules"],
      "extends": "./tsconfig.paths.json"
```

tsconfig.paths.json

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
          "@/*": ["./src/*"],
          "@Modules/*": ["./src/Modules/*"],
          "@Shared/*": ["./src/Modules/Shared/*"]
        }
      }
    }
```

craco.config.js

```
    const path = require("path");
    module.exports = {
      webpack: {
    
        alias: {
           "@Shared": path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/Modules/Shared")),
           "@Modules": path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/Modules")),
           "@": path.join(path.resolve(__dirname, "./")),
         },
      },
    };
```